# Can I use spatstat to measure spatial aggregation of the environment?

Tags: spatial, aggregation, r-package, spatstat

Currently I have individual raster data that represent the suitable environment for 18 species based on MAXENT predictions. I would like to know if the suitable environment for each species is either aggregated or not. I know that usually the R package spatsat is used to test aggregation of the spatial point pattern, but It seems that I can't not test that for the environment itself. Is that actually the case? Does any one of you would be able to direct me to a package that I could use to test aggregation of the environment?
Thanks in advance!!

TO FOLLOW UP THE QUESTION ABOVE WITH MORE DETAILS AND FIGURES

I have attached two images that I hope it makes my question more clear. So I would like to be able to quantify if the green cells (suitable environment) in figure A are more aggregated that the cells (suitable environment) in figure B. Green cells have a value of 1 and white space around then have a value of zero. I do not want to use the point locations of individuals, since I am not trying to test if the individual points are aggregated. What I was doing is using the X and Y coordinates of each green cell, but if I calculate the Clark Evans it shows is not aggregated for both. I think is because if I used the X and Y coordinates of the green cells for the Clark test all are part of a continue pattern as on figure 3. I hope this extra information is able to offer some help because I think I hit a wall now.

[Potential aggregated environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m34ym.png)

[Potential no aggregated environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rynom.png)

[Green cells X and Y coordinates used for Clark test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z3O2.png)

Comment: It is unclear to me what "aggregation of the environment" is. Try to provide more details about your problem and show example data and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spatstat` to estimate the covariance function of each environment, treating each environment as a random set. Suppose `G` is a window (class `"owin"`) representing the green cells; `R` is another window representing the red cells; and `W` is the containing window in which the environments are observed. To estimate the covariance function of the green cells you could do

```
cW <- setcov(W)
pG <- area(G)/area(W)
cG <- setcov(G)/(pG * cW)
cG[cW == 0] <- NA
fG <- rotmean(cG)
```

Then `pG` is the coverage fraction and `fG` is the (isotropic) covariance function. You could now do the same thing for `R` instead of `G`, and compare the two plots. Higher values of the covariance suggest a more aggregated environment.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! It sounds that it could work...I will try it right now!! When you said to compare the R and G plots what are you thinking?